# Jay Weinberg (Slipknot) Snare Sound

Tags: drums, metal, snare-drum, acoustic-drumset

I am a huge Slipknot fan and I recently saw a drum cam video from Jay Weinberg and I think the snare sound is absolutely incredible. The sound is created with a 48 ply snare but the snare costs 1600$ and I cant afford that. I just wanted to ask if it is possible to recreate this sound with an affordable Maple Snare.

Comment: I'm hearing compression more than anything.  His $1600 snare doesn't even sound like that in real life.

Comment: That's a take from a live mic with huge compression/limiter, that sound has absolutely *nothing* to do with the actual (or even mixed) one. You can get the same result by hitting a cardboard box with a spoon.

Comment: That's one expensive box.

Comment: To me this sounds exactly what it says - a drum cam. The sound is muted by the sheer volume of the drums. And yes, you can get this sound by hitting a (one-layer) plastic bucket. Cost = $1 (approx.).